# error 127 when running "git svn init" on cygwin

Tags: cygwin, git-svn

I'm trying to convert a local SVN repository to git using git-svn under cygwin and failing. This is what happens:

```
$ git svn init -t tags -b branches -T trunk  file:///cygdrive/e/repository/project
init: command returned error: 127
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I installed msysgit and it failed as well, but with a much better error message (Expected FS format '2'; found format '4') which turned up helpful discussions on Google. It seems like git-svn can't handle the local filesystem format of a current TortoiseSVN. The solution is to run svnserve and use the svn: protocol via localhost.